# CSS animation on button click playing only once, not playing on second click on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a dropdown menu appearing on button click. The problem is, the dropdown menus is appearing with animation all time without problem on PC, but plays with animation only once (on first click only) on mobile browsers.

```js
            function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("dropdown");
             if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
                x.classList.add("w3-show");
             } else { 
                x.classList.remove("w3-show");
             }
            }
```

```css
         #dropdown { display:none; 
border-radius: .25em;
        box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,1);
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 22px;
        color: white;
        position: relative;
        /* width:fit-content; */
        width: 250px;
        right: 0;
        left: -25px;
        margin: auto;}
        .w3-show {
            position: relative;
            display: block!important;
          }
          .w3-animate-zoom {
            animation:animatezoom 0.6s;
            -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
          }
          @keyframes animatezoom{from{transform:scale(0)} to{transform:scale(1)}}
```

```html
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="ikincibaslik" id="buttonme">Open dropdown menu</button>
                <div id="dropdown" class="show-on-scroll w3-animate-zoom" >
                        <a href="/imalat/indexfirst.php" class="w3-bar-item">First item</a>
                        <a href="/hizmet/indexsecond.php" class="w3-bar-item">Second item</a>
                </div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any animation on button click. `x.className.indexOf("w3-show")` is supposed to be `x.classList.contains('w3-show')` and it's throwing a InvalidCharacterError because you have extra spaces when when trying to add/remove the `w3-show` class.

Comment: @Spectric now I edited my post for a working "run code snippet". But the problem is it plays only once on mobile browsers. Is it an issue of the versions -o-transform -moz-transform etc? I tried that, too, but maybe missed something that I don't know

Answer (score 1):

I've got it working by making the following changes:

- indexOf is for arrays, you want to use the event listener and classlisttoggle instead: [How do I use vanilla JavaScript to write a toggle function I wrote in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539461/how-do-i-use-vanilla-javascript-to-write-a-toggle-function-i-wrote-in-jquery)
- I updated the variables (this is a style thing, not an error)
- I updated the CSS class to account for the w3-show class being added to the dropdown id, and I added a display none for the dropdown id
- I removed the onclick from the button and used the id instead (style thing) and removed the space for the added and removed w3-show class

Edit: Hat tip to this post: [keyframe animation does not work on safari for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745152/keyframe-animation-does-not-work-on-safari-for-ios) the idea is to call a separate keyframe for each browser prefix so I've added a webkit-specific one, and I realised the original animatezoom didn't have a close } bracket.

It works now:

```js
var myButton = document.getElementById("buttonme");
var dropDown = document.getElementById("dropdown");

myButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  dropDown.classList.toggle("w3-show");
});
```

```css
         #dropdown { 
         display:none; 
border-radius: .25em;
        box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,1);
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 22px;
        color: white;
        position: relative;
        /* width:fit-content; */
        width: 250px;
        right: 0;
        left: -25px;
        margin: auto;}

#dropdown.w3-show {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
      }
      .w3-animate-zoom {
        animation:animatezoom 0.6s;
        -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
      }
      
      @keyframes animatezoom{
      from{transform:scale(0)
      } 
      to
      {transform:scale(1)}
      }
      }
      
      @-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from{transform:scale(0)
      } 
      to
      {transform:scale(1)}
      }
}
```

```html
<button class="ikincibaslik" id="buttonme">Open dropdown menu</button>
                <div id="dropdown" class="show-on-scroll w3-animate-zoom" >
                        <a href="/imalat/indexfirst.php" class="w3-bar-item">First item</a>
                        <a href="/hizmet/indexsecond.php" class="w3-bar-item">Second item</a>
                </div>
```

Comment: Yes I edited my post for the button "run code snippet" to work. But the problem is it doesn't play more than once on mobile browsers. You have any ideas for that?

Comment: Hi @AnthonSanthez try again, I made an important edit removing the indexof (for checking arrays) to event listener and classlist toggle.

Comment: Hi @Nathaniel, I tried your code, it is much more simpler thanks for that, but again it is playing only once on mobile browser, as before the second click show dropdown menu without any animation:((